# Concatenating multiple string formats

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to write this more efficiently in python?

```
foo = 'title of my blog'
permalink = foo.replace(" ", "_")
permalink2=permalink.lower()
```

Having multiple string formats at once without resourcing to cascading variables to apply each new format.

Comment: `foo.str` is invalid. Did you mean something else? What is the desired output of your code? What are you trying to avoid? (Not clear at all.)

Comment: what I meant is to insert multiple formats in one line. So here I am replacing the string and then lowering the case. Is it possible to do this in one swoop?

Comment: There are no formats in your code fragment. And no cascading variables either (there is no such thing).  Do you want `foo = foo.replace(" ", "_").lower()`?